# Title in header bar is vertically misaligned on certain android devices ionic

Tags: android, css, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a little Ionic (v1.2.0) project based off the starter [side menu template](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu). I have a problem where the main title in the header bar is vertically misaligned on certain android devices.

I've posted an album with two screenshots taken on different devices.

The first screenshot was taken on a OnePlus One, Android 5.1.1 at 1080x1920. You can see the header and sub-header titles misaligned. The word "Calendar" is not in line with the menu icon, "March 2016" is not centred either.

The problem only seems to occur on certain Android devices. The second screenshot was taken on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2, Android 4.2.2, at 600x1024. It seems to be fine here.

[Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YWKj.jpg)

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Is there a fix that wouldn't break the alignment on other devices?

Thanks